Falling tank truck kills the villian
Can you help me find this movie:

Most unique thing I remember is the final scene, where a tank truck falls a -cliff and kills the villain by pressing hard on him and then exploding.
Film starts with a man and his wife driving, having trouble with an annoying car. After a stop in a gas station, their car is wrecked in the desert. A truck driver arrives, stating that since the new cars use computers he cannot repair it,  and offers to take the wife to the city for calling help. He kidnaps her (possibly to sell her kidney) and demands money from the man. (The wife has deceived the kidnapper to think they're wealthy)

Does this information ring any bells?

While reading first part, i thought its Joy Ride 2 but its not matching the other details.

This is definitely Breakdown, which starts in the way you describe:

Jeff and Amy Taylor are moving to California and must drive across the
  country. When they find themselves stranded in the middle of a desert
  with hardly anyone or anything around, their trip comes to a sudden
  halt. Amy had taken a ride with a friendly trucker to a small diner to
  call for help, but after a long time, Jeff becomes worried. He finds
  that no one in the diner has seen or heard from his wife. When he
  finds the trucker who gave Amy the ride, the trucker swears he has
  never seen her. Now Jeff must attempt to find his wife, who has been
  kidnapped and is being held for ransom. But who can he trust?

Furthermore it develops exactly like you wrote, the trucker (and a bunch of his friends) kidnapped her and wants to press money from her husband as she convinced him that they're rich. And it ends with exactly the same scene you describe (though it's a bridge instead of a cliff).
