A movie based on abduction
The movie starts with a man and his wife(not a young age couple) on a car going somewhere(probably on vacation). 
They stop at a place on the highway and the wife is kidnapped, the man tracks and hunts the kidnappers down. There were a lot of trucks in the movie. The movie maybe of 90s or early 2000s.
Unfortunately that's all I remember.

Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/13537/49 and http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/14570/49

I think that might be Breakdown with Kurt Russell and Kathleen Quinlan, who have their car break down on the highway. The driver that stops to assist them abducts the wife. Turns out it is a conspiracy, and their car was intentionally disabled. Kurt Russell's character recovers his wife and puts and end to the conspiracy.

I guess this is the one I was looking for. Thank you.
